Compatibility between Springboot 2.X and openapi-generator 7.2
Currently on a project where we work with Spring boot 2.5 and i wanna upgrade my openapi-generator from 5.3 to 7.2 i searched in mvn dependencies to look for compatibility between this version of my spring boot and the openapi-generator-maven-plugin but it wasn't mentionned anywhere. I checked different websites like https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi and https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring/ sadly i couldnt find an answer to my question. does anyone have any ideas how can solve this problem.
    <openapi-generator.version>5.3.0</openapi-generator.version>
    <openapi-springdoc.version>1.5.1</openapi-springdoc.version>
    <openapi-swagger.version>1.6.2</openapi-swagger.version>

Thank you

Just update the version in local and try running the build
